# Laplacian of a curve in a Riemannian manifold.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I have a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and a closed curve in such manifold (say $\mathcal{C}$) what I want to workout is the Laplace Beltrami operator of $\mathcal{C}$ (with the metric restricted to $\mathcal{C}$). Also assume $\mathcal{C} = \Gamma((a,b))$.

My attempt is the following. Since on $\mathcal{M}$ we have

$$
\Delta_{\mathcal{M}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \sum_{i,j} \partial_i \sqrt{|g|} g^{ij} \partial_j f
$$

My thought is to observe that on $\mathcal{C}$ we have

$$
\Delta_{\mathcal{C}} f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\sqrt{h}}{h} \frac{d}{dt}f \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \frac{d}{dt}f \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \left(- \frac{1}{2 h\sqrt{h}} \frac{dh}{dt} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \frac{d^2f}{dt^2}\right) = - \frac{1}{2h^2} \frac{dh}{dt} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{1}{h} \frac{d^2f}{dt^2}
$$

Where $h$ is the Riemannian Metric of $\mathcal{C}$, which is a positive scalar function since the dimension of the $\mathcal{C}$ is 1. Since I am restricting the metric from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{C}$ to find $h$ it can be defined from

$$
h(t) = \left\langle \frac{d}{dt} , \frac{d}{dt} \right\rangle_{\mathcal{C}}(t) = \left\langle \sum_i a_i(\Gamma(t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},  \sum_j a_j (\Gamma(t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle_{\mathcal{M}}(\Gamma(t)) = \sum_{i,j} a_i(\Gamma(t)) a_j(\Gamma(t))  \left\langle  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle_{\mathcal{M}}(\Gamma(t)).
$$

Without loss of generality I can assume the Rienmannian metric is orthonormal and therefore I can write

$$
\sum_{i,j} a_i(\Gamma(t)) a_j(\Gamma(t))  \left\langle  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \right\rangle_{\mathcal{M}}(\Gamma(t)) = \sum_i a_i(\Gamma(t))^2.
$$

By simple calculations it can be showong that each $a_i(\Gamma(t)) = \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_t (x^i \circ \Gamma) = \frac{d x^i}{dt}$, so I can write

$$
\Delta_{\mathcal{C}} f  = -\frac{1}{\sum_i \left( \frac{dx^i}{dt} \right)^2} \sum_j \frac{dx^j}{dt} \frac{d^2x^j}{dt^2} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_i \left( \frac{dx^i}{dt} \right)^2}} \frac{d^2 f}{dt^2}
$$

Are these calculations correct? I think they're cause in the case of $h = 1$ I get the second order differential operator.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: This formula looks correct to me *if* you're in a situation where $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ along the curve $\Gamma$. However, I admit to being confused about when one would be in a situation where you have the freedom to choose coordinates on $\mathcal{M}$ to make the metric orthogonal along a given curve, but not have the freedom to simply parameterize your curve by arc length (in which case, of course, $\Delta = \tfrac{d^2}{dt^2}$).